# Press enter to dodge... (Quick time event) [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, time

I've been looking all over stackoverflow for this answer but I can't seem to find any updated answers.

I want there to be a prompt that says `Press enter to dodge` (it can be any button like space if that's easier I'm guessing with `if keyboard.is_pressed`)

There must simultaneously be a timer that counts down from integer variable `timer` and when it hits zero it tells the user they were hit and sets `dodge = False`, otherwise, if they do press the key, it will tell them they dodged and set `dodge = True`

I've been trying this but it doesn't work well because it always detects that enter is being pressed no matter if they dodge in time or not :

```
from threading import Timer
dodge = False
timeout = 3 
t = Timer(timeout, print, ['You were hit!'])
t.start()
prompt = f"You have {timeout} seconds to dodge, press enter...\n" 
answer = input(prompt)
t.cancel()
if answer == " ":
  print("You didn't dodge!")
  dodge = False
else:
  print("You dodged")
  dodge = True

print(dodge)
```

Is there any other method that's easier to do this?

Please let me know if I'm missing anything... I'm still relatively new and want to learn. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things simple, you could keep track of the time when you prompt the user, and the time after they enter their response. Subtracting the two is their reaction time, which you can compare to the timeout.

```
from threading import Timer
import time

timeout = 3
t = Timer(timeout, print, ["You were hit!"])
t.start()
start_time = time.time()
prompt = f"You have {timeout} seconds to dodge, press enter...\n"
answer = input(prompt)
t.cancel()
end_time = time.time()
reaction_time = end_time - start_time
if reaction_time > timeout:
    print("You didn't dodge!")
    dodge = False
else:
    print("You dodged")
    dodge = True

print(dodge)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually really simple.